# returning something else other than Nodes

Tags: python

I'd like to count the max tree depth of a python AST. Is there a way I can do so by subclassing the `ast.NodeTransformer`? The doc says I need to return a `Node` for each of the visitor functions but I would like to return an integer instead to represent the tree depth. I looked into `ast.NodeVisitor` as well but that class doesn't have a return value for its visitor functions.